# Google Auth 1.0 access gmail unauthorized

Tags: php, oauth, gmail, google-apps

I have google apps created for my domain, it have some email addresses too,
so i'm going access there inbox email count uisng auth token and consumer secret.

the problem is i successfully get the oauth_token_secret and oauth_token and oauth_callback_confirmed

```
oauth_token={OAUTH_TOKEN}&oauth_token_secret={OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET}&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

but when i try to access gmail using above tokens it gives a error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/?oauth_token={OAUTH_TOKEN}&oauth_token_secret={OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET}&oauth_callback_confirmed=true&max-results=100)
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized in /hermes/bosoraweb022/b1554/ipg.webxtreamsnet/freelancer/auth2.php on line 85
```

Here is my code

```
<?php

$consumer = 'www.artbymargaret.co.uk';
$secret = '{CLIENT_SECRET}';
$callback = '';
$sign_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
$version = '1.0';
$scope = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom';

function urlencodeRFC3986($string)
{
   return str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($string));
}


$mt = microtime();
$rand = mt_rand();
$nonce = md5($mt.$rand);
$time = time();

$url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken';
$path = '/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken';

$post = array(
    'oauth_callback' => urlencodeRFC3986($callback),
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer,
    'oauth_nonce' => $nonce,
    'oauth_signature_method' => $sign_method,
    'oauth_timestamp' => $time,
    'oauth_version' => $version,
    'scope' => urlencodeRFC3986($scope)
);

$post_string = '';
foreach($post as $key => $value)
{
    $post_string .= $key.'='.($value).'&';
}
$post_string = rtrim($post_string, '&');

$key_parts = array($secret);

$key_parts = urlencodeRFC3986($secret);
//$key = implode('&', $key_parts);
$key = $key_parts.'&';
$base_string = 'GET&'.urlencodeRFC3986($url).'&'.urlencodeRFC3986($post_string);
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $key, true));


$post = array(
    'oauth_version' => $version,
    'oauth_nonce' => $nonce,
    'oauth_timestamp' => $time,
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer,
    'oauth_callback' => $callback,
    'oauth_signature_method' => $sign_method,
    'oauth_signature' => $signature
);        

$header_string = '';
foreach($post as $key => $value)
{
    $header_string .= $key.'="'.urlencodeRFC3986($value).'", ';
}

$header_string = trim($header_string);
$header_string = rtrim($header_string, ',');

$header[] = 'GET '.$path.'?scope='.urlencodeRFC3986($scope).' HTTP/1.1';
$header[] = 'Host: www.google.com';
$header[] = 'Accept: */*';
//$header[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$header[] = 'Authorization: OAuth '.$header_string;


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?scope='.$scope);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

 $xmlresponse= file_get_contents("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/?".$result."&mail=jane@funtastic.uk.com&max-results=100");
    print_r($out);

//die();
```

anyone know hw to access gmail inbox feed using auth 1x version with php or is there any error with my client

Answer (score 1):

The actual request you're making to the API endpoint is using just `file_get_contents` and query parameters.  With OAuth 1.0, you need to properly sign this request, and pass in an Authorization header.  You'll likely want to use the same curl code you're using above to do that.

OAuth 1.0 has 3 steps for authorization granted by an end-user:

1. App server makes a server-to-server request for an OAuth request token.
2. App server redirects user to endpoint to authorize that token.  They approve the request, and get redirected back to the app server.
3. The app server then exchanges the authorized request token for an access token.

After those steps are done, the access token is then used to sign OAuth requests to the API provider.  The signature is critical-- the access token is not used as a 'bearer token' as in OAuth 2.0.

More info here on the standard OAuth 1.0 mechanism:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#SigningOAuth

If you're trying to just make server-to-server requests without any end-user approval, you can do that for Google Apps domains you control. This does not require request tokens, access tokens, etc-- just your consumer key+secret. Here's more info on the 2-legged OAuth 1.0 mechanism for making API requests:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth#AccessFeed

Definitely agree with upgrading to OAuth 2.0 though :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation for [Google OAuth 1.0 for Apps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth#tokensGADomains), are you using the `hd` parameter?

Also, OAuth 1.0 is deprecated as of April 2012.

Comment: still prefer OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0 though !!

Comment: Yeah, lots of people do. But if OP develops using 1.0 and then Google ends support (which I'm sure they wouldn't), he'd have to move over to 2.0 anyway.

Comment: OAuth 1 will most likely be supported until [April 2015](https://developers.google.com/accounts/terms).

Comment: i send this request
$xmlresponse= file_get_contents("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/?".$result."&mail=jane@funtastic.uk.com&max-results=100");
    print_r($out);

this gets unauthorized message